# How does the caller of a function know whether Return Value Optimization was used?

Tags: c++

My understanding of return value optimization is that the compiler secretly passes the address of the object in which the return value will be stored, and makes the changes to that object instead of a local variable.

For example, the code

```
std::string s = f();

std::string f()
{
    std::string x = "hi";
    return x;
}
```

Becomes SIMILAR to

```
std::string s;
f(s);

void f(std::string& x)
{
    x = "hi";
}
```

When RVO is used. This means that the interface of the function has changed, as there is an extra hidden parameter.

Now consider the following case I stole from Wikipedia

```
std::string f(bool cond)
{
    std::string first("first");
    std::string second("second");
    // the function may return one of two named objects
    // depending on its argument. RVO might not be applied
    return cond ? first : second;
}
```

Let's assume that a compiler will apply RVO to the first case, but not to this second case. But doesn't the interface of the function change depending on whether RVO was applied? If the body of function `f` is not visible to the compiler, how does the compiler know whether RVO was applied and whether the caller needs to pass the hidden address parameter?

Comment: Every compiler can chose to do it in whatever way they want, and if its a problem for them in the case you described, they will probably chose to always use RVO. When you are intrested in how different compilers do it under the hoods, I suggest you read the generated assembler code. Use the gcc explorer for easy access to clang/gcc generated assembly.

Comment: @PlasmaHH But RVO is not always possible.

Comment: That doesn't mean the calling convention changes on when it is or it is not used. Look at some assembler how they do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no change in the interface.  In all cases, the results
of the function must appear in the scope of the caller;
typically, the compiler uses a hidden pointer.  The only
difference is that when RVO is used, as in your first case, the
compiler will "merge" `x` and this return value, constructing
`x` at the address given by the pointer; when it is not used,
the compiler will generate a call to the copy constructor in the
return statement, to copy whatever into this return value.

I might add that your second example is *not* very close to what
happens.  At the call site, you get almost always something
like:

```
<raw memory for string> s;
f( &s );
```

And the called function will either construct a local variable
or temporary directly at the address it was passed, or copy
construct some othe value at this address.  So that in your last
example, the return statement would be more or less the
equivalent of:

```
if ( cont ) {
    std::string::string( s, first );
} else {
    std::string::string( s, second );
}
```

(Showing the implicit `this` pointer passed to the copy
constructor.)  In the first case, if RVO applies, the special
code would be in the constructor of `x`:

```
std::string::string( s, "hi" );
```

and then replacing `x` with `*s` everywhere else in the function
(and doing nothing at the return).

Comment: So it adds an hidden parameter and makes the function void? (clearly under the hood)

Comment: @xanatos: there are no "void" functions on the assembler level, there are conventions for at which places return values are put and where the caller expects them, "void" is just the case where the number of return values is 0.

Comment: @PlasmaHH And there are no parameters at the assembler level... Only things that someone pushed on the stack or put in a register. We can play this game all the day. Let's say it doesn't push a return value on the stack or put it in a register, so it's similar to a void function.

Comment: @xanatos: What if your calling convention always writes return values into a place given as a pointer in some register? are all your C++ functions then void functions on that implementation?

Comment: @xanatos You could look at it like that.  When CFront used C as its intermediate language, the C function would often be declared to return `void` in such cases.  (IIRC---it's been a while since I last used CFront.)  But note that this is true for functions returning struct in C as well.  If it doesn't fit in a register, you need some convention as to where the function might put it in memory (and it can't be on the local stack, because that's disappearing).

Answer (score 4):

Lets play with NRVO, RVO and copy elision!

Here is a type:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Verbose {
  Verbose( Verbose const& ){ std::cout << "copy ctor\n"; }
  Verbose( Verbose && ){ std::cout << "move ctor\n"; }
  Verbose& operator=( Verbose const& ){ std::cout << "copy asgn\n"; }
  Verbose& operator=( Verbose && ){ std::cout << "move asgn\n"; }
};
```

that is pretty verbose.

Here is a function:

```
Verbose simple() { return {}; }
```

that is pretty simple, and uses direct construction of its return value.  If `Verbose` lacked a copy or move constructor, the above function would work!

Here is a function that uses RVO:

```
Verbose simple_RVO() { return Verbose(); }
```

here the unnamed `Verbose()` temporary object is being told to copy itself to the return value.  RVO means that the compiler can skip that copy, and directly construct `Verbose()` into the return value, if and only if there is a copy or move constructor.  The copy or move constructor is not called, but rather elided.

Here is a function that uses NRVO:

```
 Verbose simple_NRVO() {
   Verbose retval;
   return retval;
 }
```

For NRVO to occur, every path must return the exact same object, and you can't be sneaky about it (if you cast the return value to a reference, then return that reference, that will block NRVO).  In this case, what the compiler does is construct the named object `retval` directly into the return value location.  Similar to RVO, a copy or move constructor must exist, but is not called.

Here is a function that fails to use NRVO:

```
 Verbose simple_no_NRVO(bool b) {
   Verbose retval1;
   Verbose retval2;
   if (b)
     return retval1;
   else
     return retval2;
 }
```

as there are two possible named objects it could return, it cannot construct *both* of them in the return value location, so it must do an actual copy.  In C++11, the object returned will be implicitly `move`d instead of copied, as it is a local variable being returned from a function in a simple return statement.  So there is at least that.

Finally, there is copy elision at the other end:

```
Verbose v = simple(); // or simple_RVO, or simple_NRVO, or...
```

When you call a function, you provide it with its arguments, and you inform it where it should put its return value.  The caller is responsible for cleaning up the return value and allocating the memory (on the stack) for it.

This communication is done in some way via the calling convention, often implicitly (ie, via the stack pointer).

Under many calling conventions, the location where the return value can be stored can end up being used as a local variable.

In general, if you have a variable of the form:

```
Verbose v = Verbose();
```

the implied copy can be elided -- `Verbose()` is constructed directly in `v`, rather than a temporary being created then copied to `v`.  In the same way, the return value of `simple` (or `simple_NRVO`, or whatever) can be elided if the run time model of the compiler supports it (and it usually does).

Basically, the calling site can tell `simple_*` to put the return value in a particular spot, and simply treat that spot as the local variable `v`.

Note that NRVO and RVO and implicit move are all done *within the function*, and the caller needs know nothing about it.

Similarly, the eliding at the calling site is all done *outside the function*, and if the calling convention supports it you do not need any support from the body of the function.

This doesn't have to be true in every calling convention and run time model, so the C++ standard makes these optimizations optional.

Comment: if we change the example of "simple_no_NRVO" to construct the variables in the different if-else-cases, will nrvo apply?

    Verbose simple_no_NRVO(bool b)
    {
  if (b)
  {
   Verbose retval1;
   return retval1;
  }
  else
  {
   Verbose retval2;
   return retval2;
  }
    }